# Problems encountered during conversion of array string to PHP using json_decode

Tags: php

I was testing out the json_decode function which converts UTF-8 string to php variables ,

i dont understand why this does not work

```
$names='array("Jack","Jill","John")'
$convert_names=json_decode($names);
echo echo $convert_names[0];
```

But this works

```
$names='["Jack","Jill","John"]'
$convert_names=json_decode($names);
echo echo $convert_names[0];
```

I learned that the way to create a PHP array is to

```
$names=array("Jack","Jill","John") // this works
$names=["Jack","Jill","John") //this does not work
```

Why is it so different when the JSON_DECODE function is involved

Comment: "I was testing out the json_decode function which converts UTF-8 string to php variables" <- This sentence is UTTERLY false. Please read the official documentation from PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Your line `//this does not work` has mismatched bracket types `[...)` so of course it won't work. I assume you means `[...]`. In any case, the syntax you're trying to use in that line is only available in PHP 5.4 and higher, so if you're on 5.3 or earlier, no it won't work.

Comment: `'array("Jack","Jill","John")'` isn't JSON.  See: http://json.org/

Comment: Also, what's with `echo echo`????

Answer (score 1):

`array("Jack","Jill","John")` is PHP notation for an array, but invalid JSON. By coincidence, `["Jack","Jill","John"]` is valid in both PHP and JSON.

You can't use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to evaluate PHP syntax; this is what the [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function is for:

```
eval('$names = array("Jack","Jill","John");');
echo $names[0]; // Jack
```

However I'd avoid it like the plague if you can - see the caution in its documentation.

Comment: It's no coincidence that `[]` is valid PHP. the short array-syntax was introduced because of JSON's popularity... besides, your use of `eval` is both _evil_ and wrong (`eval` should contain a return statement), or an assignment

Comment: @Elias have a look at the documentation - it's not necessary: "eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned"

Comment: Yes, now your usage of `eval` will work, but originally, your code was `$convert_names=eval($names);`, which would've assigned null to `$convert_names`, that was wrong. Also: using `eval`, like you're doing in a class/function would create `$names` in the _global namespace_, not in the right scope, hence: it still is _evil_, you shouldn't show example code as dangerous as that!

Comment: Indeed I did edit - apologies! To be honest I've never used eval, but knew of its existence so thought it worth providing as an example - provided it was accompanied by an adequate warning.

Answer (score 1):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, whereas `array();` is PHP's standard way of creating new arrays. true, lately PHP supports the `[]` notation, too, but check [json.org](http://json.org/), to see what the rules are that make up *valid* json.

Another reason why your code doesn't work is `echo echo`<-- that's not right.
Also: `$names=["Jack","Jill","John")` indeed won't work because you're opening bracket isn't met with a closnig bracket, but a closing parentheses, but as of PHP 5.4 `$names = ['Jack'];` *will* work. Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)